# Create files and folder, that are always shared with the user

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

Using Google Drive API and Spreadsheet Api from c#.

How can I add folders and files (speedsheets) to a folder and make sure that they are always shared and visible to the human user?

I know about Google.Apis.Drive.Permission, but it has a daily quota, and send out an email, it does not seem like the right solution.

I would prefer to just be able to work inside a folder, and then all stuff should always be visible to both the API and the human user.

Any tips:)

Answer (score 0):

You would use the Google drive api to create a file and then add permissions on that file to share it with a user.   This is how you do it and there really isnt a better way to do it.  In order for a user to access it you must grant them permissions on it.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a permission for a file or Team Drive. 
    /// Documentation https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions/create
    /// Generation Note: This does not always build corectly.  Google needs to standardise things I need to figuer out which ones are wrong.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="service">Authenticated Drive service.</param>  
    /// <param name="fileId">The ID of the file or Team Drive.</param>
    /// <param name="body">A valid Drive v3 body.</param>
    /// <param name="optional">Optional paramaters.</param>
    /// <returns>PermissionResponse</returns>
    public static Permission Create(DriveService service, string fileId, Permission body, PermissionsCreateOptionalParms optional = null)
    {
        try
        {
            // Initial validation.
            if (service == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("service");
            if (body == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("body");
            if (fileId == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(fileId);

            // Building the initial request.
            var request = service.Permissions.Create(body, fileId);

            // Applying optional parameters to the request.                
            request = (PermissionsResource.CreateRequest)SampleHelpers.ApplyOptionalParms(request, optional);

            // Requesting data.
            return request.Execute();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Request Permissions.Create failed.", ex);
        }
    }
```

Code ripped from my sample project [PermissionsSample.cs](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Drive%20API/v3/PermissionsSample.cs)

If you are having an issue with the quota then you can try to go to google developer console and have your quota increased.  Note: Quota is based upon the number of request not the type of request you are making.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for info about permissions with example!

I found out that if you just manually create a folder that is shared read/write with the google-drive-API-email-address, and then make sure everything is going on within this folder it behaves as wanted and all files are visible to both human and computer.

Best regards Anders